# Powershell EventLog ReplacementStrings -ExpandProperty

Tags: string, powershell, split, event-log, winlogon

I need a logon database for all AD users. In order to retrofit this to past logons I am using the EventLog query in powershell. My query works:

```
Get-EventLog -ComputerName $endpoint System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon | select machinename,timegenerated,replacementstrings | export-csv c:\test.csv
```

ReplacementStrings returns an array of {1,SID}. I am using this SID as a lookup attribute to another table. I have looked online and tried to play around with expanding the property but no luck so far. As you can see I want to export this all to a csv with each event as a seperate row containing: machinename, timegenerated, and then SID (which is what I need out of replacement strings). I have also looked into using .Split[1] but cannot get that to work because I am also requesting two other objects in the same query. Thanks in advance everyone- this one has me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the structure of that data but a simple test on my own machine returns the same results. Looking at the data type it appears to just be a string *array* which is why splitting it was not working. You can tell is how it is displayed on the console with `{1, SID}`. Instead we use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to extract the second value from the `replacementstrings`.

```
Get-EventLog -ComputerName $endpoint System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon | 
        Select-Object machinename,timegenerated,@{Label="SID";Expression={$_.replacementstrings[1]}} |
        Export-Csv c:\test.csv
```

Comment: You are the man Matt! this is exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly. +1 :)

Comment: A quick followup to this- if I had multiple computer I wanted to run this through and generate 1 "master csv" for a group of endpoints (sortable by machin name or SID) would I put the export-csv command outside of the foreach loop?

Comment: @ChuckD Yes. Gather data inside loop. Do all sorting and exporting outside loop.

Comment: @ChuckD Also if this answer solved your problem consider marking it with the checkmark on the left of the question.

Comment: When I tried to export this loop it only exports the results from the first of two computers I query:                                                                                                     foreach ($endpoint in $master_roster){
$csvexport = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $endpoint System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -Newest 30 | Select-Object machinename,timegenerated,@{Label="SID";Expression={$_.replacementstrings[1]}}
}

$csvexport | Export-Csv e:\test.csv

Comment: Does this work `$master_roster | ForEach-Object {Get-EventLog -ComputerName $_ System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -Newest 30 | Select-Object machinename,timegenerated,@{Label="SID";Expression={$_.replacementstrings[1]}}} | Export-Csv e:\test.csv`? Please be aware that you are starting a new question outside the scope of the current one. A little researcher could help you find an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Matt. I had to tweak how I piped in my specific data. I can get this to work for my use case though. Very helpful and enlightening! cheers!